# Swiper carousel doesn't work in Visual studio with Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, swiper.js

Currently I try to implement a swiper carousel in an app (with cordova and ionic) but it just doesn't work.

I followed [this description](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WHIYzS994j-).

So I added this links at the top of my index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.x.x/css/swiper.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.x.x/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.x.x/js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>
```

Than I added my modified carousel code (from [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/05-slides-per-view.html)) between the `<ion-content>` tags:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

Finally I inserted the js which initializeses the slider at the end:

```
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 2,
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30
});
</script>
```

Not the forget the styles:

```
    .swiper-container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #ffd800;
}
```

And then this is what I get:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

So has someone an idea why it doesn't work?
I did exactly like they described. Even if I insert the whole, exact same css code nothing changes. It is just like a yellow div at the page, and its not possible to change the slides.
Is it because the ripple-emulator from visual studio, or maybe the js is wrong, but I copied that too.
Or have I forget something?

I found no tutorial or example how to do it with visual studio, so maybe there are some additional steps to do I don't know. I just started to learn app development.

Comment: `ionic` already has a `directive` for a swiper instance… Have you already tried using [it](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/)?

Comment: @Beat If you mean [ionic slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/) than I saw it? But can I get the same result with this? This is a full page slider, and I want multiple slides at the same page.

Comment: As you can see, [ionSlides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/) are based on **Swiper**

Comment: @Beat Yes I know, but how can I change the slide size there? So that I get at the end multiple slides at same page? I found no extra option for that. Do I have to do it on my own? If yes how can I do that, can I achieve it only with changing the css, do I have to write some js ?

Comment: try to add `height : 100%` to your `swiper-container`

Comment: @Beat I already tried this, but nothing changed. I tried to change the with and the height without success, just nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just adding the links doesn't work.
I think in cordova you work with angularjs so you need to use [angular-ui-swiper](http://nebulr.github.io/ui-swiper/).
You have to install it with bower. How you can do this is explained in the link above.